# Can a web server write to a logged-in user's screen?

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, debian

I have a very simple bash script saved in my www folder in Apache directory, which prints "website hit" whenever the php script is called.

The problem is I want that print to print on the local screen I got plugged in with the HDMI. Currently is not printing anywhere, I think it's because it's printing it somewhere else.

How can I get bash to print to a specific logged in user locally?

Comment: Logged in how? X11? Standard Linux TTY? Something else?

Comment: logged in via the terminal only, raspberry pi

Comment: The question says you want to "print to a specific logged in user". Does that **really** mean it shouldn't be printed if someone else, or nobody at all, is logged in?

Comment: i literately just want to echo a specific text to another user terminal

Comment: Yes, but is it the user that matters, or the terminal? You'd write your code differently depending on that distinction.

Comment: the terminal is the one i care about

Comment: Then why are you bothering to look up users at all (or to specify in your question that it should write to "a specific user"), if all you want is to write to the terminal, and you don't **really** want to write to a specific user at all?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a user, use the `talk` command. It has a man page: `man talk` is likely to be helpful.

If you want to write to TTY1 regardless of which user is logged in, `echo "some text" >/dev/tty1`. (Obviously, you'll need to ensure that the user running the web server has write permissions to the device).

Comment: how do i check what the user tty is?

Comment: that is what number tty is for a user?

Comment: The `who` command will tell you which users are logged in on which TTYs.

Comment: your a champ my brother